# Drawing 1 pixel wide paths in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-graphics

I am drawing a path in my drawRect implementation on a UIView with:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

With anti-aliasing on on my CGContext, I can't seem to draw 1 px lines.

[image: on]

I tried turning antialiasing off with:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
```

but then my corners look terrible:

[image: off]

How do I keep antialiasing on but stop this sub-pixel bluring of 1 pixel lines?

Comment: Core Graphics does not use pixels but points.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you draw a line in iOS, you specify the coordinates of a infinitely narrow line. The drawn line will then extend to both side of that line by half the stroke width.

If your infinitely narrow line has integer coordinates and is horizontal or vertical, the drawn line will be two pixels wide and gray instead of one pixel wide and black (with anti-aliasing). Without anti-aliasing, the line will be slightly moved but the corners look ugly.

To solve it, use coordinates in the middle of a pixel (e.g. 200.5 / 170.5) and turn anti-aliasing on.

Comment: I thought I'd tried this before and it worked, but for some reason it's not working now, and I can't understand why...

Comment: Duh! sorry, I wasn't really thinking - Retina displays obviously mean that middle of a pixel is .25, not .50 in the scaled space you draw in.

Comment: @chrism +1 that wasn't a "duh!" to me, I don't think I'd've ever figured it out if I hadn't stumbled upon it like this...

Answer (score 10):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGFloat inset = 0.5 / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // draw
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, inset);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, inset, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, inset, CGRectGetHeight(rect));
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: What's that `WKCommonUtil` thingy?

Comment: @AndréFratelli probably a 3rd framework to detect retina devices.

Comment: @AndréFratelli, this is an util class made by myself for testing if the device is retina.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate all context via:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGFloat translation = 0.5f / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, translation, translation);
... your drawing here ...
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.25)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, 0.25)

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```